Batch File should replace a string in multiple Files
I am new to batch so I tried with reading some solutions but it doesn't work for me.
I need to loop over some files and search for a string <IDOC BEGIN='1'> and replace it with <IDOC BEGIN="1">.
First I defined some variables for my filepath and use this to open a for loop to get my files. Works like a charm. Now I need to get the Filecontent and replace a specific string and save the change content to that file.
Here is my actual batch code:
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "SEARCHSTRING=<IDOC BEGIN='1'>"
set "REPLACESTRING=<IDOC BEGIN="1">"
 
if "%1" == "TP" goto VARS_TP
if "%1" == "JP" goto VARS_JP

goto ENDE
:VARS_TP
set DIVISION=
goto WEITER
:VARS_JP
set DIVISION=JP
:WEITER
set "VOLUME=D:"
set "SCRIPTDIR=%VOLUME%\Skript"
set "EDIDIR=%VOLUME%\Test%DIVISION%"
set "IN=%EDIDIR%\IN"
set "REORG=%EDIDIR%\REORG"

for %%i in (%IN%\ORDRSP*.xml) do @(
    echo %%i
    rem findstr /C:"%SEARCHSTRING%" /F:%%i 

    for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('type %%i') do (
        echo %%j
    )
)


:ENDE
endlocal && goto :eof

The echo %%j isn't called so I can't debug this.

You should be using a For /F loop! For what your current script does, change your for loop to For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /MLIC:"%SEARCHSTRING%" "%IN%\ORDRSP*.xml" 2^>NUL') Do Type "%%G". If you will only really be wanting to read the matching line, (what your rem findstr… line does), then you could probably change it to For /F "Tokens=2,* Delims=:" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"%SEARCHSTRING%" "%IN%\ORDRSP*.xml" 2^>NUL') Do Echo(%%H. The latter only works properly if the line doesn't begin with one or more colons, :.

However, I should say that you will invariably struggle to use variable expansion and replacement, i.e. %var:!SEARCHSTRING!=!REPLACESTRING!%, if either of the %SEARCHSTRING% or %REPLACESTRING% variable values contain = characters.

My immediate reaction would be to use a freeware utility like sed, awk or gawk to solve this problem.
Using batch expecting to be able to replace any general string with another is a minefield.
Perhaps it might be possible to approach the problem in another way, for instance:
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 ECHO %%e|FINDSTR /i /L /c:"%SEARCHSTRING%" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO/%%e) ELSE (
  SET "line=%%e"
  ECHO !line:'="!
 )
)

should work for the current apparent objective, to replace ' with " on lines containing searchstring. Quite how applicable this method would be to OP's situation is OP's concern.
